# Looking for opposite of pow() in PHP

Tags: php, math, linear-algebra

I am working on mathematical problem where the formula is: A[i] * (-2) power of i

where `i=0,1,2,3,...`

A is an array having values 0 or 1

Input array: `[0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1]`

Output is: `5730`

**Code**

```
$totalA = 0;
foreach ($A as $i => $a) {
     $totalA += $a * pow(-2, $i);
}
```

This is correct. Now I am looking for its opposite like:

Input is: `5730`

Output will be: `[0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1]`

I am not asking for the exact code but looking for some logic from where I should start. I tried to use log() method but that did not return the desired output.

Comment: Your first example is converting some binary (LSB first) [0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1] to decimal 5730. So basically you want to convert a decimal number e.g. 5730 to binary?

Comment: Yes but negative binary.

Comment: Well, it's not "negative binary" in the sense of "binary of a negative number". As not all decimal numbers (e.g. 3-15) are representable in your strange non-linear binary, it may be simplest to precalculate those that do, store them in a lookup table. There you go, @fafl just did it for you.

Comment: Should there be parentheses around that `-2` in your formula: in other words, should it be `A[i] * pow(-2, i)`? Due to the order of operations, what I typed differs from  what you typed.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not looking for exact code, but I found this problem too interesting. This works:

```
function sign($n) {
    return ($n > 0) - ($n < 0);
}

$target = -2396;
$i = 0;
$currentSum = 0;

// Look for max $i
while (true) {
    $val = pow(-2, $i);
    $candidate = $currentSum + $val;
    if (abs($target) <= abs($candidate)) {
        // Found max $i
        break;
    }
    if (abs($target - $candidate) < abs($target - $currentSum)) {
        // We are getting closer
        $currentSum = $candidate;
    }
    $i++;
}

$result = [];
for ($j = $i; 0 <= $j; $j--) {
    $val = pow(-2, $j);
    $border = $val / 4;
    if (sign($val) == sign($target) && abs($border) < abs($target)) {
        array_unshift($result, 1);
        $target -= $val;
    } else {
        array_unshift($result, 0);
    }
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

First I look for the `$i` that gets me on or slightly above the `$target`. When found, I walk down and decide for each bit if it should be in the result.

Comment: Thanks for attempting it but it failed with this input: [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1], output is: -2396 and with input of -2396, it not giving the expected output.

Comment: Yes it is working but output is different. It should be: [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1] rather than [0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1].

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Working :) However still looking for the more efficient approach. Thanks again.

Comment: Replaced my answer with one that runs in O(n)